# ng2-nouislider format ranges on load angular 9

Tags: angular

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-nouislider-with-form-nstwcr

Above is a link to a stackblitz with some working code.  If you move the right, 'upper range', slider and then move it back to the maximum value it will say 'Unlimited'.  When you first load it you will see the maximum range, 50000, instead of 'Unlimited'.  The lower range will also show 0 instead of $0.  How do I fix this?

```
revenueRange = [0, 500000]
revenueRangeConfig: any = {
    connect: true,
    start: [ 0, 500000], // Handle start position
    step: 5, // Slider moves in increments of '5'
    range: {
      'min': [  0, .0001 ],
      '10%': [ 1, 1 ],
      '20%': [  5 ],
      '25%': [  10 ],
      '30%': [  50 ],
      '40%': [  100 ],
      '50%': [  1000 ],
      '70%': [  10000 ],
      'max': [  500000 ]
    },
    format: {
      to:  value  => {
        if (value == 0) {
      return "$" + 0;
        } else if (value < 1) {
          let number = (value*1000).toString().substring(0, 3);
          return "$" + parseInt(number) + " Thousand";
        } else if (parseInt(value).toString().length <= 3) {
          let roundedVal = Math.round(Number(value));
          return "$" + roundedVal + " Million"
        } else if (parseInt(value).toString().length >= 4) {
          value = Math.round(value);
          let theVal = value/1000;
          let re = new RegExp("(\\d+\\.\\d{" + 2 + "})(\\d)"),
            m = theVal.toString().match(re);
          let s;
          if (m) {
            s = parseFloat(m[1])
          } else {
            s = theVal.valueOf();
          }
          if(s == "500"){
            return 'Unlimited';
          } else {
            return  "$" + s + " Billion";
          }
        }
      },
      from: value  => {
        return value;
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a custom pipe.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'revenueRange'
})
export class RevenueRangePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any) {
    if (value === 500000) {
      return 'Unlimited';
    }
    if (value === 0) {
      return '$0';
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```